# How to fix error ORA-01113 file 1 needs media recovery

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzZ05.png)I have problem with starting oracle 11g. After reboot my system oracle stop working, When I started manually I see this error:

> ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery ORA-01110: data file 1:
> 'F:\APP\A.ZARE\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF'

Comment: Looks something *bad* happened to datafile. I'm not a DBA, but - I'd think of restoring it from backup. Perhaps you'd rather ask for help on SE for DBA (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle), we're mostly developers here.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the database wasn't properly shutdown before the reboot? Regardless, the system tablespace datafile is now corrupted and will need to be restored from backup using RMAN.